# Analysing a sentence written by Woody Allen

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

The sentence below is from the piece *Udder Madness* written for *The New Yorker* by Woody Allen. I take it that Woody is no linguist and so it surprised me a good deal to light upon such a "complex" sentence from a non-linguist. I tend to believe one must have a certain level of proficiency to write such sentences.

What exactly is happening here? I can't make head nor tail of this sentence as far as its syntax and grammar are concerned. The sentence reads

> That’s why when included in last week’s A-list was a writer-director in cinema with a long list of credits although I was unfamiliar with the titles I anticipated a particularly scintillating Labor Day.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Not clear why you say Allen "is no linguist".  He was raised by German-speaking parents and was very successful as a writer for comedians and movies.  He was simply idiosyncratic in his writing/speaking style.

Comment: Didn't know that. I agree his style is certainly idiosyncratic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sentence is really not that different from

> That’s why when she smiled although I was sad I smiled too.

It could do with some commas, which becomes clear in the shorter version. All I have done is substitute:

- "she smiled" for "included in last week’s A-list was a writer-director in cinema with a long list of credits"
- "sad" for "unfamiliar with the titles"
- "smiled too" for "anticipated a particularly scintillating Labor Day"

Grammatically, the only thing making it complicated is using long phrases without any parentheses or commas to help you identify the sort of nesting in the sentence.

If I put commas in the short version:

> That’s why, when she smiled, although I was sad I smiled too.

I can try putting the same commas in the long one:

> That’s why, when included in last week’s A-list was a writer-director in cinema with a long list of credits, although I was unfamiliar with the titles I anticipated a particularly scintillating Labor Day.

And I think that makes it more readable.

Comment: Agree, but I would prefer "although..titles" in parentheses...classic snarky parenthetical remark!

Comment: I do find 'when included in last week’s A-list was a writer-director in cinema with a long list of credits,' to be a bit strange because it woud be more normal to write 'when a writer-director in cinema with a long list of credits (although I was unfamiliar with the titles) was included in last week’s A-list..'. The inversion, to me, makes it difficult to understand.